# Laravel 4 route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've got a problem with using URL::route. There is a public function in my controller called AuthController called delete_character, here's how it looks:

```
public function delete_character()
{
  $player->delete();
  return View::make('index')->with('danger', 'You have successfully deleted your character!');
}
```

Also, I've created a named route:

```
Route::post('delete_character', array(
           'as'   => 'delete_character', 
           'uses' => 'AuthController@delete_character'
          ));
```

All I want to do is to execute the `$player->delete`. I don't want it to be a site, just when I click a button it's gonna delete the player.
I've also done the button:

```
<td><a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" href="{{ URL::route('delete_character') }}"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</a></td>
```

But I constantly get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my example, I am using `GET` request method (POST is used when form is being submited, for instance) to capture this action.
I pass ID of client I wish to delete in the reqeust URL, which results into URL in this form: `http://localhost:8888/k/public/admin/client/delete/1` (You should post it from form, according to your example/request).

Not posting whole solution for you to force you to learn! My answer is not 100% identical to your situation, but will help, for sure.

```
// routes.php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::get('client/delete/{id}', 'Admin\\ClientController@delete');
});

// ClientController.php
<?php

namespace Admin;

use Client;

class ClientController extends BaseController
{
    ...

    public function delete($clientId)
    {
        $client = Client::findOrFail($clientId);

        // $client->delete();

        // return Redirect::back();
    }

    ...

}

// view file, here you generate link to 'delete' action
<a href="{{ URL::action('Admin\\ClientController@delete', ['id' => $client->id]) }}">delete</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's lot understandable now. But how could I find the players/clients id? I'm having an account, and in the account there are players. They are seperate, and each player has matching account_id. So I'm confused right now..

Comment: I added the code used to generate 'delete' link to controller's action

Comment: Well, I'm stuck again. I tried using something like this: `$player = Player::findOrFail($player->id);` , also tried using something like `$id = $player->id;`, but it still doesn't work. How is the id defined?

Comment: Gosh, where did you tried that?! In your controller's `delete` action? You are trying to retrieve!!! $player object from DB, you cannot use it to 'self retrieve' (or how could I name what you try to do)  
*1.* public function delete($playerId)**: $playerId is passed to this action  
*2.* $player = Player::findOrFail($playerId); - now you get valid player object, or 404 if not found

Comment: Oh god, I'm so stupid. I've used my own function and haven't seen there is an $playerId in the function. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad I helped. Maybe you should take a look at Routes and URL as well, helpfull reading http://laravel.com/docs/routing